# Find current day of week in c# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find current day of week in c# ASP.Net like:

```
System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

This code works well in a console application, but when I try to store the value of this line in a string in ASP.Net website it returns nothing.

Can anyone help?

```
StringBuilder message = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dayofweek = System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    String conn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OCSI;Integrated Security=True";//conne
    SqlConnection sqlconne = new SqlConnection(conn);

    string selectSQL = "SELECT lec FROM schedule WHERE [day]='" + dayofweek +"'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, sqlconne);
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        sqlconne.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        message = new StringBuider(); 
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            message.Append(reader["lec"].ToString());
           //question what are you using message for ...?
            Label3.Text = dayofweek;
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Mesage);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlconne.Close();
        // you neeed to Dispose of all other objects here too
        // StringBuilder Object
        // SqlDataReader Object
        //SqlCommand  Object.. 
        //Look into wrapping your Connection / Command Sql Dataobject around a using() {}
    }
```

I want to use current day in where clause SQL Query to get data relevant to current day from database table.

I used var as

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    String conn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OCSI;Integrated Security=True";//conne
    SqlConnection sqlconne = new SqlConnection(conn);

    var testDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();

    // string selectSQL = "SELECT lec FROM schedule WHERE [day]='" + dayofweek +"'";
    string selectSQL = string.Format("SELECT lec FROM schedule WHERE [day]= {0}", testDay);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, sqlconne);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        sqlconne.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            message += reader["lec"].ToString();

            Label3.Text = testDay;
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    { 
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlconne.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code that doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean store it in a string?

Comment: System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString(); most definitely should work in an ASP.NET application. Can only repeat what @AaronS said, please post your code that fails :)

Comment: Do you want the name of the weekday(f.e. "Wednesday") or the number? You get the name in the following way: `dateValue.ToString("dddd"))`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx

Comment: Check the code that I've pasted. Look at dayofweek string in 2nd and 6th line.

Comment: What does the `day` column of the `schedule` table contain?

Comment: @AaronS - Why? What would that do? I don't see how changing from a field to a local variable will make any difference.

Comment: nvm :P It wasn't exactly clear where the initialization was happening.

Comment: Which version of .NET, C#, SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if everything is working fine when you remove the where clause then change the Where clause to be something like this

```
   string selectSQL = string.Format("SELECT lec FROM schedule WHERE dbo.schedule.day = {0} ", testDay);
```

I would also change the name of the field day to something like DayName or something if day is a Reserved word don't use it.. 
look at this link for Reserved Words in SQL [Reserved SQL Words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

It works fine for me.

[image]

Comment: worked fine for me too... perhaps he's not doing something correctly

Comment: @Skylark555 : Yes it was from an asp.net page

Comment: Skylark555 are you sure that you understand the simple syntax that we are displaying here.. that code should work regardless if it's asp.net, console, winform, WCF, ect......

Comment: Yup I do very well but sometime little things like this make me puzzled!

Comment: @Skylark555 : Use breakpoints and see whether you have value in the variable.

Comment: ok start off by passing dayofweek as a param to the select statement look at the example below please

Answer (score 3):

Wep page is the value defined as a public , static, or property..

if you write

```
var testDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

the results will = "Friday";

Comment: it didn't get var!The type or namespace var could not be found is the error!

Comment: @Skylark555 - `var` is a keyword introduced in C# 3.0 - if you are using VS 2005 or before you can't use it.

Comment: @DJKRAZE. Friday means beer! ;)

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using..??

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010! Is there any special namespace required for var?

Comment: Dmitry it's not Pivo time yet.. or Vodka Time ...LOL that's later Friday = Happy Hour

Comment: also for testing purposes.. change your query to Select * from Schedule, I am curious if you are even getting any results back is the datasource local or on a network ..?

Comment: You can't use var outside of a method body.

Comment: please display how you are using var this should work without any problem in vs2010..

Comment: I would suggest updating the code in your post with the working changes that you have done ie a version that compiles.. and starting over from there.. this issue should not take this long..

Comment: ok for starters .. I will ask one more time.. how do you know if the reader.Execute is even working.. also in your Catch you need to trap for the exception don't just leave it blank.. where is the server where the database resides.. that needs to be in the DataSource string.. is . suppose to imply Local() also what are you updating Label3.Text = testDay; when it should not be assigned in the while loop.. since it you are looking for "Friday" you should assign the Label3.Text as this.Label3.Text = testDay; outside of the loop ... today will not change until we pass 23:59:59 make sense

Comment: Database is local and every thing is is working fine if omit the where clause.

Comment: ok what is the true name of the field [day] in the database..?

Comment: True name is day! same as above

Answer (score 0):

Also try changing your sql string to this

```
string selectSQL = 
   string.Format("SELECT lec FROM schedule WHERE [day]= {0}", dayofweek);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an integer value (system sets sunday's as 0) =

```
int day = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```